# Problem with Right-Click on Macbook Pro 9,2 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, macbook-pro, trackpad

I set up a friend's Macbook to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 with OSX. For the record, she has a Macbook Pro 9,2 (the 2012 model).

Right click didn't work out of the box. A google search got me [this post](http://www.chris-reilly.org/blog/technotes/macbook-trackpad-in-ubuntu/) (I know its for 12 but I was desparate) which suggested I install input-mtrack. I did and edited the synaptic file--which IIRC was under `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptic-SOMETHING.conf` (forgive me, I'm not in front of the computer in question right now). After restarting lightdm, the changes appeared to had done nothing.

What puzzles me is that literally no one else seems to have this problem with recent versions of Macbooks or Ubuntu. How do I go about resolving this? The trackpad is clearly set up with two buttons underneath so it can "catch" right clicks, but Ubuntu interprets both as primary buttons.

A bit extra information that may be useful: Its still completely virgin (Aside from input-mtrack its a default install) and Ubuntu recognizes a USB mouse fine (including right click).